# Framework not found MapKit

Tags: iphone, xcode, linker, mapkit

I am using **Xcode 3.2.1** in project, where **Base SDK is iPhone Device 3.0** and **iPhone OS Deployment Target is iPhone OS 2.0**, in other words a backwards compatible application.

The problem is **MapKit Framework**. It's added as **Weak linked library**, but the app just does not link for "Device - 2.2.1" target. I have run out of ideas... What else can I do but mark the library as "weak" linked? It used to work originally, but not any more.

Here's part of command line, which looks just fine to me:

```
-framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics
 -weak_framework CoreLocation -weak_framework MapKit
```

Error note:

```
ld: framework not found MapKit
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.0 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your app on 2.2.1, you don't need to choose 2.2.1 in that menu, just leave the "Active SDK" set to 3.0 or beyond.

Comment: It's the linker failure. Can't run anything, which does link first :)

Comment: wait--do you have a separate target for 2.2.1?  You don't want to compile an OS-specific binary...  Does it link if you set it to Device-3.0?  If so, that's what you should be doing, and it should still run on 2.2.1 because you weak linked.

Comment: Yep, just one target. Want to run same app as-is in both 2.x and 3.x devices. Links and runs just fine for Device-3.0 Simulator. My iPhone is still in box, using iPod Touch to test. Can't find any second place to overwrite default weak linking for MapKit, but it must be there somewhere...

Comment: Well, besides that I should NOT select target as 2.2.1, exactly like you said! I just didn't realize this, since 3.0 didn't work either, but that was due expired dev cert. Didn't notice those were two different problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [MailComposer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MailComposer/listing6.html) sample project from Apple, which does a similar thing with the MessageUI framework.  What you may need to do is set the Base SDK to 2.2.1 instead of 2.0.

Comment: Reading MailComposer, done that Weak linking. Can't find anything which might have overwritten that setting :(

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the problem and solution:

**Problem:** I wanted to create a **backwards compatible application**, which would run on both iPhone OS 2.x and 3.x devices. It would use 3.x specific features when available e.g. MapKit.

**Solution:** set your **"Base SDK as iPhone Device 3.0"** and **"iPhone OS Deployment Target as iPhone OS 2.0"**. Connect your iPhone OS 2.x device (mine was iPod Touch, where I refuse to upgrade to latest available iPod software version) and select at top left corner the **target as "Device - 3.0"** - even when your connected device is NOT 3.0 compatible at all !!!

Pretty confusing, looks totally non-logical at first, but that's the way it works!